# PHP replace regex with pattern inside subject string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm not really sure how to word the title but I'm trying to achieve the following:

`$string = 'category/(.*)/page/([0-9]+)'` and I need to turn that into `category/test/page/2` by means of passing an array of parameters like so:

```
Array
(
    [0] => test
    [1] => 2
)
```

Doing `$string = preg_replace('#^'.$string.'$#', $replacements, $string)` results in an error about `$replacements` being an array, which matches what [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) says, however I'm not sure how else to go about it.

I can't really get my head around the pattern and subject begin the same string.

Comment: The first parameter of the regex is the pattern, not the string. Is that a typo? You should provide the three values those are so issue can be reproduced.

Comment: So, you want to replace the `(.*)` and the `([0-9]+)` in your string?

Comment: Sorry, I think that's where I'm confusing myself; I've reworded the question a bit and added my missing delimiters. The subject string is the same string that has the pattern, and yes I just need to replace those bits with what's passed through.

Comment: Do you have to pass an array and want the path like structure as output?

Comment: If you are searching the regex then it's not going to be numbers it is going to be `[0-9]+`. I don't understand why you'd be searching a regex...

Comment: How are you getting this string input: `$string = 'category/(.*)/page/([0-9]+)'`?

Comment: It's a URL routing system; this regex is used to match a URL but I also need to try and use the same regex to output a link to said URL, with values in place of the capture groups, which is what `$replacements` is.

Comment: @MattRogowski: In that case, wouldn't you want to run `preg_replace` on the URL itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have a make a *new* regex to match what you want in the string.  You'll have to make something that matches the literal strings `(.*)` and `([0-9]+)`.  Something like this, perhaps:

```
/(.+)\/(\(.+\))\/(.+)\/(\(.+\))/
```

Then you can try to do this:

```
$string = preg_replace('/(.+)\/(\(.+\))\/(.+)\/(\(.+\))/', '$1/test/$3/2', $string);
```

Or using `$replacements`:

```
$string = preg_replace(
    '/(.+)\/(\(.+\))\/(.+)\/(\(.+\))/',
    '$1/'.$replacements[0].'/$3/'.$replacements[1],
    $string
);
```

DEMO: https://eval.in/435153

Comment: Thank you; this works well and is kinda what I thought I'd have to end up doing, however the pattern in `$string` is used for URL routing and could have complex capture group patterns in it itself, which is why I was hoping to be able to somehow use that same string as the pattern to match. It may well be the case that I can't do that, in which case this is great, thanks.